# getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

Can somebody in plain words explain me the usage of `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` methods of `ArrayAdapter`?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

These handle the case where you want different **types** of view for different rows. For instance, in a contacts application you may want even rows to have pictures on the left side and odd rows to have pictures on the right. In that case, you would use:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}
```

The framework uses your view type to decide **which views to hand you via `convertView` in your `getView` method**. In other words, in the above example, your even rows will only get recycled views with pictures on the left side to reuse, and odd rows will only get ones with pictures on the right.

If every row in your list has the same layout, you don't need to worry about view types. In fact, [BaseAdapter.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java;h=532fd766ec66ae54a6e4b3def4b8bdc839c1db7a;hb=refs/heads/master) provides a default behavior for all adapters:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

This indeed provides you with the same view type for every row.

**Edit** - to outline the general flow:

1. You bind data to your `AdapterView` using an adapter.
2. The `AdapterView` tries to display items that are visible to the user.
3. The framework calls `getItemViewType` for row `n`, the row it is about to display.
4. The framework checks its recycled views pool for views of row `n`'s type. It doesn't find any because no views have been recycled yet.
5. `getView` is called for row `n`.
6. You call `getItemViewType` for row `n` to determine what type of view you should use.
7. You use an if/switch statement to inflate a different xml file depending on which view type is required.
8. You fill the view with information.
9. You return the view, exiting `getView`, and your row's view is displayed to the user.

Now, when a view is recycled by scrolling off the screen it goes into a recycled views pool that is managed by the framework. These are essentially organized by view type so that a view of the correct type is given to you in `convertView` parameter in your `getView` method:

1. The framework again calls `getItemViewType` for the row it wants to display.
2. This time, there is a view in the recycled pool of the appropriate type.
3. The recycled view is passed to you as the `convertView` parameter to your `getView` method.
4. You fill the recycled view with new information and return it.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for your answer. Can you describe the flow how these methods are invoked. Also I don't understand how this is actually associated with my data in res/layout.

Comment: There isn't an explicit contract for when these methods are invoked. res/layout is the place for **view** objects. This is an **adapter**. You should check the item type in your getView method and inflate the proper view from res/layout accordingly.

Comment: You are returning it yourself in getItemViewType.

Comment: You do the association manually in getView: if (type == 0) { /* inflate R.layout.row_icon_on_left */ } else { /* inflate R.layout.row_icon_on_right */ }

Comment: You could also return the layout you want to use as your view type for simplicity, since it is also an int.

Comment: Beware! getItemViewType() must return an int between 0 and getViewTypeCount() - 1.

Comment: good answer, can you please share the docs supporting your explaination?

Comment: If you were hoping to use this with a Spinner, you're out of luck: "On API LOLLIPOP and above, attempting to set an adapter with more than one view type will throw an IllegalArgumentException" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Especially, the description of the flow particularly helped clear the confusions in my mind.

Comment: @MatthewWillis can explain how to implement getItemId with setHasStableIds.

Comment: As @PacificSky, said and is written in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter#getItemViewType(int): `Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1. IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE can also be returned.` I didn't know that and used numbers from 1 to getViewTypeCount(). In `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)` you receive a `viewType` that is set by `getItemViewType(int position)`. Strange, but it works in my case. In https://stackoverflow.com/a/36917425/2914140 Randika Vishman wrote it might be a problem with jumbling, but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 12):

If we need to show different type of view in list-view then its good to use `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in adapter instead of toggling a view `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` can be very expensive task inside `getView()` which will affect the list scroll.

Please check this one for use of `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in Adapter.

Link : [the-use-of-getviewtypecount](http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2014/06/the-use-of-getviewtypecount-and.html)

Comment: Returning IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE in  getItemViewType() will always pass 'view' as null in getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) forcing to initialize all the UI components. Is not that a bad performance indicator wherein in case of holder pattern, we get to reuse existing UI views and we can simply toggle the view to View.GONE or View.VISIBLE based on position.

Answer (score 12):

**Watch Outttt!!!!** 
I had to face for a problem implementing a `ListView` yesterday and it's two types of views for rows got jumbled just after I scroll it. Even though the top voted answer within this thread gives a good general explanation it hasn't highlighted the most important bit of information to stop the above UI bug which I have mentioned.

**Here is my explanation:** 
Both `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` are being used by `BaseAdapter`'s `getView` method to find out which type of a view should it be fetch, recycled and returned. (as explained in the top answer within the thread). But if you don't implement these two methods intuitively according to the Android API Doc, then you might get into the problem I mentioned about.

**Summarized Guideline for the implementation:** 
To implement multiple types of `Views` for `ListView`'s rows we have to essentially implement, `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods. And `getItemViewType()` documentation gives us a Note as follows:

> **Note:** Integers must be in the range `0` to `getViewTypeCount() - 1`.
>   `IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` can also be returned.

So in your `getItemViewType()` you should return values for the View Type, starting from 0, to the last type as (number of types - 1). For example, let's say you only have three types of views? So depending on the data object for the view, you could only return **0** or **1** or **2** from the `getItemViewType()` method, like a zero-based array index. And as you have three types of views used,
your `getViewTypeCount()` method must return 3.

In any case if you return any other integer values like 1, 2, 3 or 111, 222, 333 for this method you definitely might experience the above UI bug which you just placed by not obeying to the Android API Doc.

If you didn't get the clue or couldn't still resolve and need further information please read my [detailed answer within this StackOverflow Q&A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897195/1752988).

Read the [Android Developer Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) for further information you might be find the clue directly.

Hope this answer might be helpful to someone out there to save a lots of hours!!!

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for mentionning `IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` I had a bug on one of my ListView. I used an ArrayAdapter to insert a view composed of 1 image and 2 text view. I had only one view type. I tried either to not Override the method getItemViewType, or to Override it by returning the position or a hard-coded integer. In all cases, I was experiencing duplicates in my list, with odd behaviour when scrolling (duplicates changes). Returning `IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` in the method fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex glad it was helpful for you! :-)