# Creating listview items programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have data from a WS that need to be shown on an Android ListView.
Data can be of different types, so i need to dynamically create a layout for ListView items, how can i do it? I think i have to use LayoutInflater but have always used it with existing layouts and never created a layout from scratch. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to create adapter for that

just check this link it elaborate all about using adapters.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

// edited

in the given url just check this code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = values[position];
        if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

where R.layout.rowlayout is the layout for your each row 
in which you can define your imageviews,textviews

Comment: vogella site has great tutorials but cannot find an example with a layout created from scratch where views are add added; all the examples i see use a pre-existing xml layout that is inflated. I wanted to avoid this.

Comment: ok then why dont you try to create them by new object as ListView list = new ListView(context));

Comment: No, because i don't need to add a new ListView but, inside the ListView for every row, i need to add items as TextView or ImageView. I think to have to used something similar to your solution in getView but have not idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you're using different datatypes, I assume you want to show different layouts per datatype. It's not necessary to dynamically create your listview-items; if you want, you can just inflate them from XML.

Create a custom listadapter (see the link to vogella provided by vipin) and override the `getView()`, `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods.

In `getView()` you build your views either programmatically or inflate them from XML. To determine which layout to inflate (or build), call  `getItemViewType(position)`, check the value it returns and then choose which layout to inflate for that value. For more info on how to build XML-layouts, see [this page in the dev guide on XML layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Next, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301093/710990) and implement this into your adapter. Be sure to also read the comments. For example, override `getItemViewType()` with something like:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(getItem(position) instanceOf ItemA) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This approach allows your listview to recycle views and use the ViewHolder-pattern (for more info, again see the link vipin provided).