# Why does the Android View API care about an ArrayAdapter's getViewTypeCount?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, recycle

I've been learning about creating custom `ArrayAdapter`s and have familiarized myself with overriding an ArrayAdapter's `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` methods.

Why does the Android View API care about the 'number of possible view types' returned by `getViewTypeCount` ? And, as the programmer, why should *I* care?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do recipes promote overriding getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount when it doesn't seem necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270143/why-do-recipes-promote-overriding-getitemviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-when-it-d)

Comment: It's related (I'm the author of both) but I chose to keep the questions atomic/separated.

Comment: To re-emphasize the point of this question, realize that this question isn't about recycling or using custom views -- I'm asking, "why do Android gotta know/care 'bout the number of custom views, since it retrieves that specific view type from getItemViewType?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just reviewed the Android source to see exactly where `getViewTypeCount` is used. It's in the abstract `AbsListView` class' inner `RecycleBin` class' `setViewTypeCount` method.

This `setViewTypeCount` method is used to specify the initial size of the `ArrayList<View>` of `scrapViews`. This `ArrayList` itself is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<View>`s -- one for each "view type count."

Furthermore the value returned by `getViewTypeCount` is assigned to `RecycleBin`'s member variable `mViewTypeCount`. This member is used to control the logic for recycling for cases where there is only one vs. many views throughout a handful of methods in the RecycleBin class(as everyone has been alluding to).

So the answer is, I believe, that `getViewTypeCount` is used by `RecycleBin` so that it knows whether it has just one or numerous Views to handle. So to speak.

(Thanks everyone for opening my eyes to recycling and motivating me to read the source.)

Answer (score 2):

**Commonsware**'s answer on your previous question explained very well why do you need to care about those methods. Here is a small example:

You have a `ListView` with 100 rows and 3 types of rows:

1. a simple `TextView`
2. a custom view (very complex)
3. an `AnalogClock` view

You `ListView` starts like this:

- position 0: TextView <= *first visible position*
- position 1: custom view
- position 2: custom view
- position 3: TextView
- position 4: AnalogClock <= *last visible position*
- position 5: custom view <= *first invisible position(here android will provide a recycled view)*
- position 6: TextView

If you don't implement those methods then android will simply recycle the views not taking in consideration the type of rows. So in the example above, when the user scrolls the `ListView` down the `getView` method will be called for row `5` with a recycled view(the row 0 that isn't visible anymore), a `TextView`(`convertView` will not be `null` for this position). As you see this isn't the view you would expect at that position. Because in the `getView` method you have something like this:

```
   //...
       if (convertView == null) {     
          // inflate views
       } else {
         //just use it    
   //...
```

you'll end up setting data on a row that should be a `custom view`(very complex) but instead get a simple `TextView`. This will get worse as you further scroll the `ListView` up and down.

If you do implement those methods then android will know that the `getView` method will expect 3 types of rows. When row 5(from the previous example) needs to be shown android will call `getItemViewType` to see what type of view the `getView` method expects for that position(position 5). If a recycled view of that type is found(previously recycled) then the `getView` method will be called with `convertView` set to that recycled view, if not then the `getView` will be called with `convertView` set to `null`. As you scroll the `ListView` to show the position 5 the(only) recycled view will be the simple `TextView`. The `getView` method expects a `custom view`(very complex) and as a recycled view isn't found with that type then the `convertView` will be `null` and you get the chance to inflate it.

If you scroll the `ListView` to show position 6 the view from position 1(that isn't on the screen anymore) will be recycled so the `ListView` has now two views of different types(`TextView` and a `custom view`(very complex)). Then the `getItemViewType` will be called again and for this position the `getView` method requires a `TextView`. A recycled view of this type exists so the `getView` method will be called with `convertView` set to this recycled `TextView`. If you further scroll the `ListView` and the `getView` requires a `TextView` or a `custom view` one of those recycled views(with the correct type) will be supplied. Also, eventually a view of type `AnalogCLock` will be recycled so the `ListView` will have recycled views of each list row type to reuse.

Comment: I really like this explanation of recycling. However, this answer is more relevant to [Why do recipes promote overriding getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount when it doesn't seem necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270143/why-do-recipes-promote-overriding-getitemviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-when-it-d). My question is, specifically, why does the number of custom views matter, per `getViewTypeCount` ?

Comment: @ybakos: "My question is, specifically, why does the number of custom views matter, per getViewTypeCount ?" -- that drives the number of object pools it maintains for recycling, AFAIK. You are welcome to sift through the `AdapterView` code to try to get at more details.

Answer (score 1):

In [the reference, it says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) "Each type represents a set of views that can be converted in getView(int, View, ViewGroup)."

If the views are different, then they cannot be recycled with incompatible other views. So if this method returns anything different from `1` the standard `onView` recycling code will not work anymore.