# Approach for Android List with different row layouts

Tags: android, listview

I have to use different layouts for each row, and i am following a simple approach and i want to confirm whether i am going in correct direction.

1) I am keeping a Weak reference of views for reusing.

```
    private WeakReference<View> mLocationView;
    private WeakReference<View> mGallaryView;
    ..
```

2) And then while loading i am checking

```
    if (mGallaryView == null || mGallaryView.get() == null) {....

       //Inflating XML

        mGallaryView = new WeakReference<View>(convertView);

    }else {
        convertView = mGallaryView.get();
    }
```

Am i doing it correctly or there is any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am i doing it correctly

No.

> there is any other way?

Step #1: Override `getViewTypeCount()` in your `ListAdapter` and return how many different types of rows you have (e.g., 2). Let's call this value `N`.

Step #2: Override `getItemViewType()` in your `ListAdapter` and return a number, from 0 to `N-1`, indicating the particular type of row to use for this `position`.

Step #3: In your `getView()` method, just return the right row layout for the given position. The `convertView` will either be `null` (so you create a new one) or it will be a row of the right type (so you just use it).

See also:

- [Why do recipes promote overriding getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount when it doesn't seem necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10270143/115145)
- [getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5300962/115145)
- https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView
- http://antew.com/?p=162

and countless other sources.

Comment: Thanks Mark!! Yup! i got it now. I was confused about how android is going to handle row reusing. Thats why i kept WeakReference of views.. I thought i am going to have atmost 6 rows, i can do it this way.