# ListView that mixes simple_list_item_1 and simple_list_item_2

Tags: android, listview, android-2.2-froyo

I want a ListView which displays name and info about each item using `simple_list_item_2`, so it looks something like this:

```
SWITZERLAND
a country with many delicious cheeses

BRITAIN
famous for its clocktower

AUSTRALIA
in Australia, everything is upside down!
```

The text in caps is meant to represent the large black text in each ListView element and the lower caps text represents the grey, small type of that element.

However, I want the user to be able to add his own countries, so the first element would show up as

```
ADD NEW COUNTRY...
```

Without any small-type text. I can use `simple_list_item_2` and simply set the small text to `""`, but this aligns the large text awkwardly. I want this special "add new country" element to look exactly like `simple_list_item_1`.

However, the decision to use `simple_list_item_1` or `simple_list_item_2` is made in the initialization of my adapter:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
            myListOfListViewElements);
```

And then this decision is realized when I populate the ListView:

```
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So how can I use both kinds of simple_list_item in one ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You could always your "Add new country" as a header view by calling `addHeaderView(View view)` on the `ListView` before you call `setAdapter(adapter)` / `setListAdapter(adapter)`.  Attach an onClick listener to that header view to capture any clicks

That way your "Add new country" will show as the first entry in your listview

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case where you're dealing with just a single 'special' item, @dymmeh's answer is definitely a good and easy to implement approach. For the more generic case, where you need to deal with multiple different items that need not necessarily sit at the top of the `ListView`, you can refer to the following two methods in an adapter:

- `getItemViewType(int position)`
- `getViewTypeCount()`

Based on the return value of the first method, Android will feed you the desired `convertView` in the adapter's `getView(...)` method. A common approach is to simply return the layout ids as type (e.g. `R.layout.row_layout`) , but you can really use anything you like, provided the values uniquely identify a type.

After that, you'll need to do a little bit of extra work to inflate the correct layouts when constructing your ViewHolder/RowWrapper. For each view type, you'll need to pick the right layout if `convertView == null`. There will be at least one view type (which is the default case) and at most `getViewTypeCount()`. [An example illustrating the idea can be found here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

More details on the view type methods:

- [getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter)

On a side note: I'd actually consider not making the 'add...' option part of the `ListView`, but rather position it on top of or above it so that it's conveniently accessible; i.e. no need to scroll back to the top first.