# Scroll a view in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a view with three linear layouts and listview.I want to scroll the entire view while scrolling the list.Is it possible? Scrollview not worked.Please help me .thanks in advance

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#9d9d97" />
          </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#9d9d97" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#9d9d97" />

   </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:textColor="#9d9d97"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#9d9d97" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:longClickable="true" >
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user1767260 post your xml.

Comment: @user1767260: ListView itself is a scrollable View so no its not the best practise to use ScrollView for a ListView (as a parent view). and keep in mind scroll view only works for one child view( you can have multiple childs (view) inside child view (layout) of ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

Putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView` is not a good idea.

Either make your three `LinearLayouts` headers like here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter or make them part of the adapter using `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` and returning them from `getView`: [getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter).