# ListView displaying different objects

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to wrap my head around listview with viewHolder based on performasnce issues. I have two lists, items and categories. These will be compined into one list so that I can use use getItemViewType() to difference between what kind of view to inflate.

The datafields in these items are ofcourse different. Using one viewHandler is not possible as far as i understand. That being said, my list will not likely be longer than 150 items, so is using viewHolder-pattern all togeheter necesarry?

I have to relativeLayouts that is suppose to be used. One for the items, which contains several textViews, two buttons and maybe one editText-field, and one relativeLayout for category that contains one textView and one button.

All the examples I've seen around maybe contains different xml-files for the layouts, but all xml-files contains the same datafields and ids so it makes sence using one viewHandler.

Is it possible to do what I', trying to explain here? Populate a listView with two different RelativeLayouts that is totally different when it comes to layoutdesign, datafields and ids?

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: if your question is 2 different layout per item on listview,, yes its possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter)