# initialize RelativeLayout in this getView, programmatic view generation

Tags: android, getview, convertview

I am using a getView in an adapter where I am creating an imageview and making that equal to convertView where the view has already been initialized before. It contains image thumbnails, some of which represent videos.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        // First check if this is the top row

        if (position < mNumColumns) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new View(mContext);
            }
            // Set empty view with height of ActionBar
            //convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            //      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
            return convertView;
        }

        // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize
            imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        } else { // Otherwise re-use the converted view
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // Check the height matches our calculated column width
        if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        if(images.get(position - mNumColumns).getUriString().contains("video")){
            //display video icon
        }
        else
        {
            //don't display video icon
        }

        // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
        // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
        if (images != null && !images.isEmpty())
            mImageFetcher.loadImage(images.get(position - mNumColumns).getUriString()/*.imageUrls[position - mNumColumns]*/, imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
```

The thumbnails do not have a "play" button on them to designate that they are videos, so in those cases I need to add a play button, programmatically.

Typically I use a viewholder pattern with an inflated layout, I am not doing that in this case because I actually don't want some things in memory.

So instead I want to programmatically make a RelativeLayout as the root view of each cell (`mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView`) and add the imageview and playbutton imageview into that convertview

How do I do that? It requires modification of this statement but I'm not sure how to initialize all the re-used views

```
   } else { // Otherwise re-use the converted view
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
```

Comment: why you gendering programmatic view, you can use xml

Comment: i have answer for your question but using xml file, in which i showing play button.

Comment: @lokeshjoshi786 now do it programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make your `getView()` always return a `RelativeLayout` object (which I call `containerView` below) to which you add your `ImageView(s)` as children.

The only complication here is that you need to give these children identifiers so that you can retrieve them from a recycled `convertView` later.  Note that I used the built-in, static `View.generateViewId()` for this, which is API level 17.  If you need it to work pre-API-level-17 you can create your own ids using unique integers (such as 1, 2, etc.) -- just make sure they aren't greater than `0x0FFFFFF`.  **Update:**  I added code that I use for this below.

See the comments I added in several points below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    // First check if this is the top row
    if (position < mNumColumns) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new View(mContext);
        }
        // Set empty view with height of ActionBar
        //convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
        //      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
        return convertView;
    }

    // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
    RelativeLayout containerView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView videoIconView;   // TODO:  or whatever type you want to use for this...
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize
        containerView = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        // TODO:  The layout params that you used for the image view you probably 
        // now want to use for the container view instead...
        imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);   // If so, you can change their name...

        imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);   // This probably isn't needed any more.

        // Generate an Id to use for later retrieval of the imageView...
        // This assumes it was initialized to -1 in the constructor to mark it being unset.
        // Note, this could be done elsewhere in this adapter class (such as in
        // the constructor when mImageId is initialized, since it only
        // needs to be done once (not once per view) -- I'm just doing it here
        // to avoid having to show any other functions.
        if (mImageId == -1) {
            mImageId = View.generateViewId();
        }
        imageView.setId(mImageId);

        containerView.addView(imageView, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // NOTE:  At this point, I would personally always just add the video icon
        // as a child of containerView here no matter what (generating another unique 
        // view Id for it, mVideoIconId, similar to how was shown above for the imageView) 
        // and then set it to either VISIBLE or INVISIBLE/GONE below depending on whether
        // the URL contains the word "video" or not.  
        // For example:
        vidoIconView = new <whatever>;
        // TODO:  setup videoIconView with the proper drawable, scaling, etc. here...
        if (mVideoIconId == -1) {
            mVideoIconId = View.generateViewId();
        }
        videoIconView.setId(mVideoIconId);
        containerView.addView(videoIconView, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)containerView.getLayoutParams());
        layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   // ... or whatever else you want
        layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);  // ... or whatever else you want
    } else {
        // Otherwise re-use the converted view
        containerView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        imageView = containerView.findViewById(mImageId);
        videoIconView = containerView.findViewById(mVideoIconId);  // see comment above
    }


    // Check the height matches our calculated column width
    if (containerView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
        containerView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
    }

    if(images.get(position - mNumColumns).getUriString().contains("video")){
        //display video icon
        // see comment above, here you can probably just do something like:
        videoIconView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        //don't display video icon
        videoIconView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // could also use INVISIBLE here... up to you.
    }

    // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
    // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
    if (images != null && !images.isEmpty())
        mImageFetcher.loadImage(images.get(position - mNumColumns).getUriString()/*.imageUrls[position - mNumColumns]*/, imageView);
    return containerView;
}
```

---

**Update:**
In response the question in the comments, I use something like this (in my custom "ViewController" base class):

```
private static int s_nextGeneratedId = 1;

/** 
 * Try to do the same thing as View.generateViewId() when using API level < 17.
 * @return Unique integer that can be used with setId() on a View.
 */
protected static int generateViewId() {
    // AAPT-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
    if (++s_nextGeneratedId > 0x00FFFFFF)
        s_nextGeneratedId = 1;  // Roll over to 1, not 0.
    return s_nextGeneratedId;
}
```

Note that you do not need a unique view id for every single cell in your grid.  Rather, you just need it for each type of child view that you might want to access using `findViewById()`.  So in your case, you're probably going to need just *two* unique ids.  Since the view ids auto-generated from your xml layout files into your `R.java` typically are very large, I've found it convenient just to use low numbers for my hand-generated ids (as shown above).

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate on how the View.generateViewId() would work if I had to make my own ids? I feel like I'd have to use a random number generator here since I won't be able to reference other cells

Comment: @CQM I just updated my answer to address that.  In particular, I don't think you'll need to use a random number generator.  You can probably simply use `1` and `2`, say `1` for `mImageId` and `2` for `mVideoIconId`.  (I'm assuming you aren't hand-generating view ids anywhere else in your app.)

Comment: I was trying to make this one work before awarding the bounty, but was/am still having difficulties before StackOverflow autoselected. It is a better answer than the XML one

Comment: @CQM thanks.  let me know if you're still having troubles with it.  I'm happy to try to help more.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach here would be to use an Adapter that returns *different* types of views (by overriding [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)), for example as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter).

That way you do not need to programmatically alter the returned views, at all. Just define two XML layouts and inflate/reuse either one or the other according to whether the item at that position has a video or not.

Not only would this be clearer, you wouldn't have the performance penalty of "transforming" one view into the other whenever a video-row is supplied as `convertView` for another item without one, or vice-versa

Comment: sure, so this is more about how to programmatically make the second view. This question doesn't involve defining an XML layout at all :) I know how to do this with XML