# How can I fill the first line in a list view before filling it with my custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I want to fill the first listview line with an int from another method in my databasehelper, and the fill the rest of the view.

All I can find googleing this is how to do it with an ArrayAdapter

this is how i fill the view now:

```
        new Handler().post(new Runnable(){          
        @Override
        public void run(){
            cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactDBHelper.listAll());

            listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }

    });
```

what I want to do is to fill the first line with the coming int from this method.

```
contactDBHelper.countContact();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use a header view on your list for that? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

Comment: Been looking on that, but cant seem to grasp how it works

Comment: It works just like any other view on your layout. Just add a new `TextView` to your layout xml file, find it after inflating or setting the content view, set its text to the result of `countContact()` and add it as a header for your list. Here's a link to a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Comment: create a TextView set text countContact and add it as header view to list view as `listview.addHeaderView(view);`

Comment: listView.addHeaderView is not allowd

Answer (score 0):

try using ListVew.addHeaderView(View view)

```
    ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TextView header=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    header.setText("Header");
    lv.addHeaderView(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) methods if you want to display different views at the `ListView`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter) is a short example.