# ListView holder with a dynamic number of elements

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, android-viewholder

Here is the problem i am facing. I am developing a custom list view in which a single list view item is consisted of multiple text and image views. But depending on the item properties it sometimes needs to have 4 TextViews sometimes 1, sometimes 6.... the number is dynamic and i am having trouble figuring out how to developed a proper view holder pattern that will work.

I can not solve the problem by creating a number of TextViews and hiding them and displaying when necessary, since i dont know how many of them are necessary per item.

And inflating them dynamically and adding to the layout every time in getView is disastrous  to say the least :(

Is it a viable solution to have an array list of Views in the holder and then work something out?

Comment: use jababeen SetGet Methed and Asssin True and false on textview item if true than show textview if false hide text view i think i undersatnd

Comment: You didnt understand my question, my view holder doesnt hold a static number of views

Comment: have u not fix like 10 text view

Comment: It might be a quick fix, but what happens if there is more then 10?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the adapters view types: [getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int))
The number of view types depends on how many permutations are needed to represent all the varying ways an individual list item will look.

So if there are 4 different UI looks, then you'd have 4 different view types. You'd then have a ViewHolder representing each type. Then in the `getView()`, you just detect which type is represented by the position and inflate/populate as needed.  You won't need to worry about hiding different portions of the UI to change up the look.  The adapter will ensure you are only given a recycled view for the proper type.

For a nice detailed explanation of using the view type, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter).

Comment: The sollution cant be applied to my case since i dont have a static number of view types...over a hundred combinations come to mind... I have implemented arraylists of views in viewholders and with some debugging works like a charm.

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of combos.