# How to inflating another layout inside bindView?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

How I can inflating another layout in bindView? I can with condition change layout.

For example: if(condition) show blank layout

My Code:

```
 @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        final int goftarId = cursor.getInt(holder.column_id);


        if(deleteListId.contains(goftarId)) {
            // not worked !!!!
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.blank_row, null, false); 
        } else {
            // not worked !!!!
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.default_row, null, false);
        }

        holder.tvText.setText(cursor.getString(holder.column_gtext));
    }
```

It is very important for me to be optimized.

If you know a better solution, please say me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want exactly is to use `RecyclerView` to show different items. If so, check my codes [RecyclerView with different items](https://github.com/LittlePanpc/RecyclerViewTest/blob/master/src/com/example/recyclerviewtest/adapter/MyRVAdapter2.java). You will know how to achieve this after reading.

PS: if you are using `ListView`, then maybe you need to check [getItemViewType() and getItemTypeCount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter).

Comment: Thanks. yes i need this, but i using normal ListView !!