# Android: Not sure why my listview is getting all jumbled up?

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment

I implemented a ListView that worked correctly until I added more than 5 items and 2 headers. Im not entirely sure why some items are not appearing and others are appearing multiple times. Any assistance in fixing this will be much appreciated. Code is include below.

Toolbox.java

```
public class Toolbox extends Fragment {
    private ListView lstView;
    private View rootView;
    List<Tools> tools;

    public static Toolbox newInstance(Context context) {
        Toolbox fragment = new Toolbox();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Toolbox() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Technical Toolbox");
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbox, container, false);
        lstView =(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        //final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) recView.findViewById(R.id.reView);


        setToolBoxData();
        setToolBoxAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setToolBoxAdapter() {
        ListArrayAdapter adapter = new ListArrayAdapter(getActivity(),tools);
        lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setToolBoxData(){
        tools=new ArrayList<>();
        tools.add(new Header("Languages"));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Android",R.drawable.ic_android));
        tools.add(new ListItem("XML", R.drawable.ic_xml));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Java",R.drawable.ic_java));
        tools.add(new ListItem("JavaScript", R.drawable.ic_javascript));
        tools.add(new ListItem("C++", R.drawable.ic_cpp));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Visual Basic", R.drawable.ic_vb));
        tools.add(new ListItem("HTML", R.drawable.ic_html));
        tools.add(new ListItem("CSS", R.drawable.ic_css));
        tools.add(new Header("Source Control"));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Git", R.drawable.ic_git));
        tools.add(new ListItem("GitHub", R.drawable.ic_github_cat));
        tools.add(new ListItem("SourceTree", R.drawable.ic_sourcetree));
        tools.add(new ListItem("BitBucket", R.drawable.ic_bitbucket));
        tools.add(new Header("DataBase"));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Parse", R.drawable.ic_parse));
        tools.add(new ListItem("MS Access", R.drawable.ic_access));
        tools.add(new ListItem("SQL", R.drawable.ic_sql));
        tools.add(new Header("Design & IDE Tools"));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Android Studio", R.drawable.ic_androidstudio));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Visual Studio", R.drawable.ic_visual_studio));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Genymotion", R.drawable.ic_genymotion));
        tools.add(new ListItem("Ionic", R.drawable.ic_ionic));
        tools.add(new Header("Office Tools"));
        tools.add(new ListItem("MS Project", R.drawable.ic_project));
        tools.add(new ListItem("MS Visio", R.drawable.ic_visio));
        tools.add(new ListItem("MS Excel", R.drawable.ic_excel));
        tools.add(new ListItem("MS Word", R.drawable.ic_word));
    }
}
```

ListArrayAdapter.java

```
public class ListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tools> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public enum RowType{ LIST_ITEM, HEADER_ITEM }

    public ListArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Tools> tools){
        super(context, 0, tools);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount(){return RowType.values().length;}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int pos){return getItem(pos).getViewType();}

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);
        View View;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (rowType) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
                    holder.View=getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_title, null);
                    holder.View=getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public  View View;
    }
}
```

Tools.java

```
public interface Tools {
    public int getViewType();
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);
}
```

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem implements Tools {
    private final String str1;
    private final int pic1;

    public ListItem(String text1, int pic1) {
        this.str1 = text1;
        this.pic1 = pic1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return ListArrayAdapter.RowType.LIST_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        ImageView picture1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        text1.setText(str1);
        picture1.setImageResource(pic1);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Header.java

```
public class Header implements Tools {
    private final String         name;

    public Header(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return ListArrayAdapter.RowType.HEADER_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        text.setText(name);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only populating your row widgets in the `if (convertView == null)` case. If `convertView` is not `null`, you are simply returning it unchanged, meaning it will have data from some prior `position`, not the `position` that is being requested.

IOW, you need to call methods like `setText()` and `setImageResource()` on **every** `getView()` call, to fill in the row's widgets with the data for the requested `position`.

Comment: so what your saying is that i need to get rid of the if (convertView==null) case and just have my switch statement?

Comment: @8BitYoda: Possibly. Basically, you seem to be delegating inflation and view population to the `getView()` methods of `Header` and `ListItem`. In that case, the `getView()` at the adapter should only pass control to `Header` and `ListItem`. Those classes can then decide whether to inflate or recycle, and then populate the widgets in either case.

Comment: Removing the 'if' 'else' statement fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out. When I coded this I half followed a guide and half went from memory so I imagine that's where I was getting crossed up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Brief background:**

Actually I came through this same error today. As it is described I've also done 90-95% identical implementation. However I saw the accepted answer of this Q&A thread also. But I couldn't agree with you! So I searched and searched why my simpler `ArrayAdapter` implementation wasn't working properly. At the first time it loads Okay. But soon after I scroll it once? All the types of rows go jumbled-bumbled!

**Summarized Answer:**
Read the [Android Developer Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) for further information you might be find the clue directly. To implement multiple types of `Views` for `ListView`'s rows we have to essentially implement, `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods. And `getItemViewType()` documentation gives us a Note as follows:

> **Note:** Integers must be in the range `0` to `getViewTypeCount() - 1`.
>   `IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` can also be returned.

So in your `getItemViewType()` you should return values for the View Type, starting from 0, to the last type as (number of types - 1). For example, let's say you only have two types of views? So depending on the data object for the view, you could only return 0 or 1 in the `getItemViewType()` method.

If you didn't get the clue or couldn't still resolve and need further information please read it down the bellow:

**Detailed Explanation:**

> According to the Android Developer Documentation or the API Doc, it
>   has mentioned that in order to implement multiple types of views within
>   `ListView` adapter, we have to implement the following methods:

```
public int getItemViewType (int position)
public int getViewTypeCount ()
```

> And out of the above two methods, `getItemViewType` is essential in our
>   case (where we have multiple view types). That's true right? So what?
>
> That's where me and **@8BitYoda** has gone wrong. The OP's wrong thing was he had defined an `Enum` where it doesn't give types as range of `integers` within the range of 0 to `(getViewTypeCount() - 1)`.

And what I had done was, I had defined the types as follows:

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;
```

And at first I haven't implemented, `getViewTypeCount()`, so I implemented it as follows:

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 2;
}
```

Then soon after I run the app and try to load that view with the ListView, it crashed giving me the following exception:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6643)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1292)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
>   :
>   :
>   :
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Say what? :O

It indirectly says that it's related with the integer I'm returning from the method `getViewTypeCount()`, as I'm returning 2. And I return 2 because I have only two types. So I went back to the Android Documentation seeking the final help. And it really helped me and resolved my question, by reading the doc which relates to the methods I have implemented.

For a quick snap, have a look at the image bellow:
[image]

[With a tiny little font, it has given a ***NOTE*** for us.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

What does the note of `getItemViewType (int position)` method says?

> **Note:** Integers must be in the range `0` to `getViewTypeCount() - 1`.
>   `IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` can also be returned.

So right after seeing this I understood that I need to re-assign the `type integers` I'm sending to starting from 0 to whatever the number of types I have, like zero based array index. So I re-corrected those two lines and it worked like a charm afterwards!

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
```

Sorry, I know my answer went a little longer than I expected, almost like a mini tutorial. But it's okay for me I spent around an hour+ to write this because I'd to spend around 5 hours to figure out this silly mistake. Who thinks that types should be assigned starting from 0, like 0-based array index?

So I hope my answer might be helpful to somebody out there to resolve this error.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using positions, you should use some form of id for uniqueness.

Also as the views are recycled, you need to update them with new data.

```
if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
                holder.View=getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_title, null);
                holder.View=getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    //here update the holder in else case also.
    }

    return convertView;
```