# android - several layouts in cells in listview

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater, listviewitem

I need that my ListView support different layouts depending on some condition, but it's not working and layout is the same in every cell. Here is a part of my code that unfortunately isn't working:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] sSecondStartTimeArray;
    private final String[] sSecondEndTimeArray;
    private final String[] sSecondTitleArray;
    private final String AllData2;
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context,
                         String[] sSecondStartTimeArray, String[] sSecondEndTimeArray, String[] sSecondTitleArray, String AllData2) {
        super(context, R.layout.relcell2main, sSecondStartTimeArray);
        this.context = context;
        this.sSecondStartTimeArray = sSecondStartTimeArray;
        this.sSecondEndTimeArray = sSecondEndTimeArray;
        this.sSecondTitleArray = sSecondTitleArray;
        this.AllData2 = AllData2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            int resource;
            switch (HTTPRequestSecond.GetSecondType(AllData2, position)) {
                case "rest":
                    resource = R.layout.relcell2second;
                    break;
                default:
                    resource = R.layout.relcell2main;
                    break;
            }
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }
        //some code (it's now working properly even without this part)
        return convertView;
    }
```

"rest" result exists, I checked. But not working anyway.

Comment: Any errors? It may be related to your `inflater.inflate` method, it throws a `InflateException` if theres an error.

Comment: @ErickFilho no errors, just the same layout everywhere :(

Comment: Only `relcell2main` is shown?

Comment: @ErickFilho Yup. But for now it's alright, getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount() really helped. But I wonder why inflaters don't inflate XMLs in their original ways? Actually, cells sometimes don't look like corresponding XMLs (e.g., they finally may be de facto "wrap_content" in width despite the original was "match_parent", and inflaters ignore some xml tags (e.g., margin)). Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Never experienced such a thing, my cells are just like the xml I design.

Comment: @ErickFilho what type of layout do you use in cells? "margin"-tags work too?

Comment: Yea, `layout_margin` works. As well as, `padding`.

Comment: @ErickFilho and what type of Layout is the best way to use as mark-up for cells?

Comment: I have cells using Frame, Relative and Linear. It really depends, however you should always keep it simple. So if you can use Linear, use it.

Comment: @ErickFilho and is it possible to make different cell height in one ListView? I parse data from Internet so the height of each cell should be dynamic, but everywhere I have the same height as the first cell.

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible. Try something like setting parent layout's height to `wrap_content` and then having a TextView with your parsed data. Take a look at TextView docs to wrap the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getItemViewType()`. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter) and tutorial [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).