# Android: Spinner adapter view type count must be 1

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, illegalargumentexception

Hello I run in a trouble running the app in Android 5.1 emulator. I have a screen contains Spinner.This Spinner works fine on my phone running android 4.0+. I received an error like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Spinner adapter view type count must be 1
>               at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:439)

I have override a method like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    if (hasTitle())
        return _models.length+1;
    else
        return _models.length;
}
```

I know the _models.length is greater 0 when I debug it. GetItemViewType not get hit during debugging.

The main problem is I have two screen that has two spinner. The first screen is working after using the above code but the second screen not that lucky.

Does any have an idea why the error appear even though my _models does have value in it.

Sorry, I may have missed read the error.. Must be 1... But why must be 1??

Comment: Please show more of your adapter code

Comment: getViewTypeCount() must be >= 1. This is because you need to have at least 1 type of View otherwise the adapter makes no sense. The only possiblity is that in your second screen _models.length == 0 and hasTitle() == false.

Comment: Thanks I have changed to 1 now and its ok

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009697

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make getViewTypeCount return 1.

This method allows you to inflate different layouts for different items. It, along with getViewType(), makes sure the correct type of View gets passed to getView() as convertView

Comment: what does it mean by inflate different layouts for different items?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter

Comment: Understood, could you answer my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286008/how-to-start-task-periodically-using-firebase-job-scheduler