# Unable to implement stable ids for different view holder in recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
>   Where to create ids?

I'm creating a blogging app where i have different viewholder. For views to disable shuffle, and to provide correct positioning i need to provide stable ids. Hence I need to know the correct process of overriding `getItemId()`.

Comment: Its also better if you say, what do you want to achieve...?

Comment: @Xenolion i m creating a blogging app where i have different viewholder and for views to disable shuffle and to provide correct positioning i need to provide stable ids, hence i need to know the correct process of overriding getItemId().

Comment: Now I have got you, You should override the method `getItemViewType` in your adapter and return different ints depending on the View Type lets say form  Swaggish view holder return 1 for that position, for a shuffle view holder return 3 or else. And getViewType in the onCreate and onBindViewHolder

Comment: Stable ids, complicated..

Comment: any reference code for this??

Comment: Check the documentation or start here for any adapter even recyclerView adapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter